# Generate reports for multiple testng suits/classes/multiple suits in one suit using ExtentReports 3.2 jar java

Tags: java, testng, extentreports

> I'm new to ExtentReports. I have gone through many videos in youtube
>   to generate reports using ExtentReports with above titled conditions
>   but didn't find the exact answer for which I was looking for.
>
> When tried to execute multiple classes in a testng suite it says
>   nullpointerexception For suppose just assume suite contains 3
>   classes(Test cases). For first class execution goes smoothly. Once it
>   jumps to the second class it says NullPointerException. Below is my
>   code

Note: Tried with @BeforeTest and @AfterTest toooo...

```java
public class AppInit {

    public ExtentReports reports;
    public ExtentTest testInfo;
    public ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void reportSetup() {
        htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/AutomationReports.html"));
        htmlReporter.loadXMLConfig(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/resource/XML/Extent-Config.xml"));
        reports = new ExtentReports();
        htmlReporter.setAppendExisting(true);
        reports.setSystemInfo("Environment", "Automation");
        reports.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void testMethodName(Method method) {
        String testName = method.getName();
        testInfo = reports.createTest(testName);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void capture_TestStatus(ITestResult result) {
        try {
            if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
                testInfo.log(Status.PASS, "Test method " + "'" + result.getName() + "'" + result.getStatus());
            } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
                testInfo.log(Status.FAIL, "Test method " + "'" + result.getName() + "'" + result.getStatus());
                testInfo.log(Status.FAIL, "Test error " + result.getThrowable());
            } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
                testInfo.log(Status.SKIP, "Test method " + "'" + result.getName() + "'" + result.getStatus());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {    
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void generateReport() {
        reports.flush();
    }
}
```

Exception/Error

> Mar 30, 2018 10:21:07 PM
>   main.java.com.xxx.yyy.framework.LogTestListener log
>       INFO: test.java.com.xxx.yyy.tests.modules.zzz.explore.Attributes#serialNumber
>   starting
>       Mar 30, 2018 10:21:21 PM main.java.com.xxx.yyy.framework.LogTestListener log
>       INFO: test.java.com.xxx.yyy.tests.modules.zzz.explore.Attributes#serialNumber
>   completed
>       Mar 30, 2018 10:21:21 PM main.java.com.xxx.yyy.framework.LogTestListener log
>       INFO: test.java.com.xxx.yyy.tests.modules.zzz.explore.Capacity.aaa#poolName
>   starting
>       Mar 30, 2018 10:21:21 PM main.java.com.xxx.yyy.framework.LogTestListener log
>       INFO: test.java.com.xxx.yyy.tests.modules.zzz.explore.Capacity.aaa#poolName
>   skipped
>       Mar 30, 2018 10:21:21 PM main.java.com.xxx.yyy.framework.LogTestListener log
>       INFO: test.java.com.xxx.yyy.tests.modules.zzz.explore.Capacity.aaa#poolUsable
>   starting
>       Mar 30, 2018 10:21:21 PM main.java.com.xxx.yyy.framework.LogTestListener log
>       INFO: test.java.com.xxx.yyy.tests.modules.zzz.explore.Capacity.aaa#poolUsable
>   skipped
>       Tests run: 9, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 7, Time elapsed: 38.356 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
>       testMethodName(test.java.com.xxx.yyy.tests.modules.zzz.explore.Capacity.aaa)
>   Time elapsed: 14.078 sec  <<< FAILURE!
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>         at main.java.com.xxx.yyy.framework.AppInit.testMethodName(AppInit.java:178)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:653)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
>         at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
>         at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
>         at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
>         at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:37)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:368)
>         at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$2.call(ThreadUtil.java:64)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> ```
> Results :
>
> Failed tests: 
> test.java.com.xxx.yyy.tests.modules.zzz.explore.Capacity.aaa.testMethodName(test.java.com.xxx.yyy.tests.modules.zzz.explore.Capacity.aaa)
>   Run 1: aaa>AppInit.testMethodName:178 » NullPointer
>   Run 2: PASS
>
>
> Tests run: 7, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 5
>
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] Total time: 43.588 s
> [INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-30T22:21:22+05:30
> [INFO] Final Memory: 21M/259M
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test
> ```
>
> (default-test) on project Framework: There are test failures.
>       [ERROR] 
>       [ERROR] Please refer to C:\bbb\Project_Workspace\Framework\target\surefire-reports for the
>   individual test results.
>       [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
>       [ERROR] 
>       [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>       [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>       [ERROR] 
>       [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>       [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Executing single TestNg suit(with mulitple classes) in maven. The suite looks like this

```xml
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="ReportLibrary_Inventory_Test" parallel="tests">

    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="main.java.com.xxx.yyy.framework.LogTestListener"/>
    </listeners>

    <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
    <parameter name="sUsername" value="aaa" />
    <parameter name="sPassword" value="bbb" />

    <test name="zzz_ReportLibrary_Inventory" enabled="true" preserve-order="true" group-by-instances="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="test.java.com.aaa.yyy.tests.modules.zzz.reportlibrary.inventory.ccc"></class>
            <class name="test.java.com.aaa.yyy.tests.modules.zzz.reportlibrary.inventory.ddd"></class>
            <class name="test.java.com.aaa.yyy.tests.modules.zzz.reportlibrary.inventory.eee"></class>
            <!-- <class name="test.java.com.aaa.yyy.tests.modules.zzz.reportlibrary.inventory.Sample"></class> -->
            <class name="test.java.com.aaa.yyy.tests.modules.zzz.reportlibrary.inventory.fff"></class>
            <!-- <class name="test.java.com.aaa.yyy.tests.modules.zzz.reportlibrary.inventory.ggg"></class> -->
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Executing Multiple testng suites in in maven(pom.xml)

```xml
<suiteXmlFiles>
    <!-- <suiteXmlFile>src/resource/TestNg_XML/zzz_ReportLibrary_Inventory.xml</suiteXmlFile> -->
    <!-- <suiteXmlFile>src/resource/TestNg_XML/zzz_ReportLibrary_Summary_TableView.xml</suiteXmlFile> -->
    <suiteXmlFile>src/resource/TestNg_XML/zzz_Explore_Attributes.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    <!-- <suiteXmlFile>src/resource/TestNg_XML/zzz_All.xml</suiteXmlFile> -->
</suiteXmlFiles>
```

Please help me in resolving this issue. I'm running out of time to deliver

Thanks in advance:)

Appint class code

```
package main.java.com.xxx.zzz.framework;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.Status;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentHtmlReporter;

import page.pageactions.LoginPageActions;
import page.pageactions.reportlibrarypageactions.ReportLibraryPageActions;
import test.java.com.xxx.zzz.tests.modules.centralizedManagement.Collecting;
import test.java.com.xxx.zzz.tests.modules.centralizedManagement.Modify_PollingInterval;

public class AppInit {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public String convertStatus;
    public String className;
    public String testCase_MethodName;
    public final static int Timer_Web_Element_Show = 30;

    public static String retrievedUserEnteredbbbNamezzzUI;

    public ExtentReports reports;
    public ExtentTest testInfo;
    public ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;

    // XML Parser
    public static String resBodyXMLFilesPath;
    public static File file;
    public static DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory;
    public static DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
    public static Document doc;
    public static XPath xPath;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void reportSetup() {

        htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/AutomationReports.html"));
        htmlReporter.loadXMLConfig(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/resource/XML/Extent-Config.xml"));
        reports = new ExtentReports();
        htmlReporter.setAppendExisting(true);
        reports.setSystemInfo("Environment", "Automation");
        reports.attachReporter(htmlReporter);

    }

    @BeforeSuite
    @Parameters({ "browser", "sUsername", "sPassword" })
    public void setup(String browser, String sUsername, String sPassword) throws Exception {

        DataProviders.getPropertyData();
        CommonMethods.deleteFilesFromDirectory("TestCaseResult_FolderPath");
        // CommonMethods.deleteFilesFromDirectory("DownloadedFiles_Path");

        // Check if parameter passed from TestNG is 'firefox'
        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
            FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
            profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
            profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
            profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir",
                    CommonMethods.relativePath("", "\\src\\resource\\Downloaded_Files"));
            profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile",
                    "application/log,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;");
            profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
                    "application/log,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;");
            profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
            profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
            profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false);
            profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
            profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
            profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", false);

            // create firefox instance
            // System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette",
            // ".\\geckodriver.exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
        }
        // Check if parameter passed as 'chrome'
        else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            // set path to chromedriver.exe
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                    CommonMethods.relativePath("chromedriver.exe", "\\src\\lib\\"));
            // create chrome instance
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        } else {
            // If no browser passed throw exception
            throw new Exception("Browser is not correct");
        }

        driver.get(CommonMethods.dp_DataCollector("url"));
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // Logging into zzz
        LoginPageActions.username(sUsername);
        LoginPageActions.password(sPassword);
        LoginPageActions.loginButton();


          Modify_PollingInterval.modify_TopologyPolling(); System.out.println(
          "Topology polling executed successfully");
          Modify_PollingInterval.modify_PerformancePolling();
          System.out.println("Performance Polling executed successfully");

          System.out.println("Modifying level and log file size started");
          CommonMethods.ssh_ExecuteCommand("Collector_UserName",
          "Collector_Password", "Collector_IP", "Collector_Port",
          "sed -i 's/INFO/FINEST/g' /opt/APG/Collecting/Collector-Manager/yyy-aaa/conf/logging.properties && (>&2 echo 'Success') || (>&2 echo 'Fail')"
          ); CommonMethods.ssh_ExecuteCommand("Collector_UserName",
          "Collector_Password", "Collector_IP", "Collector_Port",
          "sed -i 's/1048576/1000048576/g' /opt/APG/Collecting/Collector-Manager/yyy-aaa/conf/logging.properties  && (>&2 echo 'Success') || (>&2 echo 'Fail')"
          ); System.out.println("Modified level and log file size");

          System.out.println("Re-Starting collector manager started");
          CommonMethods.ssh_ExecuteCommand("Collector_UserName",
          "Collector_Password", "Collector_IP", "Collector_Port",
          "apg-collector-manager-yyy-aaa restart  && (>&2 echo 'Success') || (>&2 echo 'Fail')"
          ); CommonMethods.pauseTime(8); System.out.println(
          "Restarted collector manager");

          System.out.println("Verifying one successful poll");
          CommonMethods.polling_Check("Collector_UserName",
          "Collector_Password", "Collector_IP", "Collector_Port");
          System.out.println("One successful polling is done");

          System.out.println("Downloading the log file");
          CommonMethods.ssh_DownloadLogFile("Collector_UserName",
          "Collector_Password", "Collector_IP", "Collector_Port");
          System.out.println("Downloaded log file");

          CommonMethods.get_ResponceBodyfromLog(CommonMethods.
          retrieveLatestFileName_Downloaded().toString(),
          "CreateNew_LogFile_aaa", "StartPoint_aaa", "EndPoint_aaa");

          Collecting.dataBase_ImportPropertiesTask(); System.out.println(
          "Property store executed successfully");


        // Holding XML data in a doc for parsing it
        resBodyXMLFilesPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + CommonMethods.dp_DataCollector("CreateNew_LogFile_aaa");
        file = new File(resBodyXMLFilesPath + ".xml");
        dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        retrievedUserEnteredbbbNamezzzUI = ReportLibraryPageActions.retrieveUserEnteredbbbName();
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void testMethodName(Method method) {

        String testName = method.getName();
        testInfo = reports.createTest(testName);

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void capture_TestStatus(ITestResult result) {

        try {


            if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
                testInfo.log(Status.PASS, "Test method " + "'" + result.getName() + "'" + result.getStatus());
            } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
                testInfo.log(Status.FAIL, "Test method " + "'" + result.getName() + "'" + result.getStatus());
                testInfo.log(Status.FAIL, "Test error " + result.getThrowable());
            } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
                testInfo.log(Status.SKIP, "Test method " + "'" + result.getName() + "'" + result.getStatus());
            }



        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }



    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void generateReport() {

        reports.flush();

    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void tearDown() {

        CommonMethods.pauseTime(5);

        // reports.flush();

        driver.quit();

    }

}
```

Modified code as suggested

```
public class AppInit implements ISuiteListener, IInvokedMethodListener {
    public void onStart(ISuite suite){

            //Extent Reports
            htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/AutomationReports.html"));
            htmlReporter.loadXMLConfig(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/resource/XML/Extent-Config.xml"));
            reports = new ExtentReports();
            htmlReporter.setAppendExisting(true);
            reports.setSystemInfo("Environment", "Automation");
            reports.attachReporter(htmlReporter);

            DataProviders.getPropertyData();
            CommonMethods.deleteFilesFromDirectory("TestCaseResult_FolderPath");
            // CommonMethods.deleteFilesFromDirectory("DownloadedFiles_Path");

            // Check if parameter passed from TestNG is 'firefox'
            String getBrowserInput = suite.getParameter("browser");
            if (getBrowserInput.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
                FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
                profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
                profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
                profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir",
                        CommonMethods.relativePath("", "\\src\\resource\\Downloaded_Files"));
                profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile",
                        "application/log,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;");
                profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
                        "application/log,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;");
                profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
                profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
                profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false);
                profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
                profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
                profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", false);

                // create firefox instance
                // System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette",
                // ".\\geckodriver.exe");
                driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
            }
            // Check if parameter passed as 'chrome'
            else if (getBrowserInput.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
                // set path to chromedriver.exe
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                        CommonMethods.relativePath("chromedriver.exe", "\\src\\lib\\"));
                // create chrome instance
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
            } else {
                // If no browser passed throw exception
                try {
                    throw new Exception("Browser is not correct");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            driver.get(CommonMethods.dp_DataCollector("url"));
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            // Logging into aaa
            String getUserName = suite.getParameter("sUsername");
            String getPassword = suite.getParameter("sPassword");
            LoginPageActions.username(getUserName);
            LoginPageActions.password(getPassword);
            LoginPageActions.loginButton();

            resBodyXMLFilesPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + CommonMethods.dp_DataCollector("CreateNew_LogFile_bbb");
            file = new File(resBodyXMLFilesPath + ".xml");
            dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            try {
                dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

            retrievedUserEnteredcccNameaaaUI = ReportLibraryPageActions.retrieveUserEnteredcccName();

        }

        public void onFinish(ISuite suite) {

            CommonMethods.pauseTime(5);

             reports.flush();

            driver.quit();

        }

        public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {

            String testName = method.getTestMethod().getMethodName();
            testInfo = reports.createTest(testName);

        }

        public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
            if (testResult.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
                testInfo.log(Status.PASS, "Test method " + "'" + testResult.getName() + "'" + testResult.getStatus());
            } else if (testResult.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
                testInfo.log(Status.FAIL, "Test method " + "'" + testResult.getName() + "'" + testResult.getStatus());
                testInfo.log(Status.FAIL, "Test error " + testResult.getThrowable());
            } else if (testResult.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
                testInfo.log(Status.SKIP, "Test method " + "'" + testResult.getName() + "'" + testResult.getStatus());
            }

        }
}
```

output after removing listeners

> [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO]
>   [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building aaa 3.7-SNAPSHOT [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources
>   (default-resources) @ aaa --- [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy
>   filtered resources. [INFO] Copying 14 resources [INFO]  [INFO] ---
>   maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ aaa --- [INFO]
>   Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date [INFO]  [INFO] ---
>   maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ aaa
>   --- [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources. [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\zzz\bbb\aaa\src\test\resources
>   [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile
>   (default-testCompile) @ aaa --- [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling
>   the module! [INFO] Compiling 13 source files to
>   C:\zzz\bbb\aaa\target\test-classes [INFO]  [INFO] ---
>   maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ aaa --- [INFO]
>   Surefire report directory: C:\zzz\bbb\aaa\target\surefire-reports
>
> -------------------------------------------------------  T E S T S
>   ------------------------------------------------------- Running TestSuite java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:210)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.(FluentWait.java:94)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.(WebDriverWait.java:70)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.(WebDriverWait.java:44)
>     at
>   page.pageactions.CommonMethodsPageActions.clickOnUI(CommonMethodsPageActions.java:24)
>     at
>   test.java.com.xxx.yyy.tests.modules.ccc_ddd.reportlibrary.inventory.eee.poolName(eee.java:19)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:37)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:368)  at
>   org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$2.call(ThreadUtil.java:64)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Tests run: 2, Failures: 1,
>   Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.799 sec <<< FAILURE! - in
>   TestSuite
>   diskName(test.java.com.xxx.yyy.tests.modules.ccc_ddd.reportlibrary.inventory.disks)
>   Time elapsed: 2.071 sec  <<< FAILURE! java.lang.NullPointerException:
>   null  at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:210)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.(FluentWait.java:94)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.(WebDriverWait.java:70)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.(WebDriverWait.java:44)
>     at
>   page.pageactions.CommonMethodsPageActions.clickOnUI(CommonMethodsPageActions.java:24)
>     at
>   test.java.com.xxx.yyy.tests.modules.ccc_ddd.reportlibrary.inventory.disks.diskName(disks.java:21)
>
> Results :
>
> Failed tests:    disks.diskName:21 » NullPointer
>
> Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
>
> [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 9.667 s [INFO] Finished at:
>   2018-04-03T18:47:16+05:30 [INFO] Final Memory: 21M/259M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test
>   (default-test) on project aaa: There are test failures. [ERROR] 
>   [ERROR] Please refer to C:\zzz\bbb\aaa\target\surefire-reports for the
>   individual test results. [ERROR] -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see
>   the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>   [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible
>   solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the way in which you are making use of `@BeforeSuite` and `@BeforeTest` annotations.

`@BeforeSuite`/`@AfterSuite` annotated methods will be executed only once per `<suite>` tag by TestNG. So lets say your `<suite>` contains two or more `<test>` tags, even then TestNG will execute them only once.

`@BeforeSuite`/`@AfterSuite` annotated methods will be executed only once per `<test>` tag by TestNG. So lets say your `<test>` contains two or more classes, even then TestNG will execute them only once.

It looks like all of your test classes are basically extending the class `AppInit`.

So only for the first class in your `<test>` the `@BeforeSuite` and `@BeforeTest` will be executed. From the second class onwards it will be skipped, even though the second class also has that method as part of your inheritance.

You would need to employ a different mechanism to use `ExtentReports`. I would suggest that you make use of TestNG listeners wherein you build a listener that implements `org.testng.ISuiteListener` and move your `@BeforeSuite`/`@AfterSuite` logic into this listener and in the same implementation, have your class also implement `org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener` and move your `@BeforeMethod`/`@AfterMethod` logic into this implementation.

Finally you wire in this listener into your suite.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Based on your suggestion I modified my code but still facing the same issue.
Request to send me the code. I'm sending my total class(AppInit) code. Please help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks a lot:)

Comment: Above is the original code of AppInit class. I'm not sending the modified code(suggested) because its to clumsy which may not be clear for you to understand.
Please help me.

Comment: Your stacktrace still indicates that there was a problem with invoking a configuration method. But what you added as an update to your question indicates you are using a listener. These two dont see to correlate. Please check what you have as code at your end and update the post with the proper stacktrace

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried removing the listeners from my testng.xml. But still getting the same exception which is NullPointer.
Please help me in getting it resolved by sharing the code snippet. Coming Thursday is my delivery date. Please help me.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your `NullPointerException` is arising out of your test method and not from your listener. I suggest that you please share your test class etc., and open up a new post. Your original issue stands resolved i believe

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I try executing my code by commenting extent reports code with configs, it runs smoothly. I think their is an issue with my extent report configuration itself.
Without extentreports mulitple suits,classes execution is going smoothly only when try executing with extentreports it throws nullpointer exception.
Above are the config code(AppInit.java) and testng.xml files. Please help me by sharing the code snippet configuration of extentreports.
Thank you:)

Comment: When executing the code without ExtentReports config. Below is the result
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 106.194 sec - in TestSuite
Results :
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:51 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-04T14:28:36+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/197M
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

Finally was able to resolve. It was a small mistake i.e. instead of using static variable I was using a normal one.

```
@BeforeSuite
// Invoking ExtentReports functionality
public void reportSetup() {

    htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/AutomationReports.html"));
    htmlReporter.loadXMLConfig(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/resource/XML/Extent-Config.xml"));
    reports = new ExtentReports();
    reports.setSystemInfo("Environment", "Automation");
    reports.attachReporter(htmlReporter);

}

@BeforeMethod
public void testMethodName(Method method) {

    String testName = method.getName();
    testInfo = reports.createTest(testName);

}

@AfterMethod
public void capture_TestStatus(ITestResult result) {

    try {

        if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
            testInfo.log(Status.PASS, "Test method " + "'" + result.getName() + "'" + result.getStatus());
        } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
            testInfo.log(Status.FAIL, "Test method " + "'" + result.getName() + "'" + result.getStatus());
            testInfo.log(Status.FAIL, "Test error " + result.getThrowable());
        } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
            testInfo.log(Status.SKIP, "Test method " + "'" + result.getName() + "'" + result.getStatus());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}

@AfterSuite
public void tearDown() {

    CommonMethods.pauseTime(5);
    reports.flush();
    driver.quit();

}
```